# Storing API Keys submitted by client in frontend

Tags: api, security, passwords, secure-coding

I know API keys need to be stored securely and should not be accessible client side.  That being said, I also know that a lot of Wordpress plugins/ custom sites/ and such allow users to copy paste the API key into a text input on the admin panel.

My question is how do you do this securely? Do they hash it and save it to their database?

Say for example I made a react app or wordpress plugin that allowed users to do something with the Google Maps API. I know I can go get their API key and just hard code it in... but if I wanted to let the user update the key on their own - What would be the reccomended steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want your application to process secrets of third party APIs. A bit scary, but if you get the user consent - why not? First thing first - make sure the user understands what he is doing. Point out exactly what you will do with the API keys, what you will not do with the API keys and how will they be protected.

Personally I would never want to store such secrets in my own database, as this would be a single point of failure. When you are hacked, everyone is hacked. Why not put such secrets in - say - local storage so it never touches one of your servers?

Ok, in case it is your server that needs to do something, you could get the API key passed in a request, do something, but never log or persistently store the secret anywhere.

In case it is enough for the Java Script to do the job, local storage is even better solution.

One could think about encrypting the keys in the local storage, but I don't believe this would improve security a lot. I mean this would be security through obscurity and could by bypassed by someone with physical access to the machine/browser/user agent. But if someone would have such access, then probably some of the API keys would be one of the smaller problems.

Comment: I think this is exactly the advice I was looking for!   Honestly - I am just wondering how people do this in general, because I know it's done a lot! I don't believe I have ever used Local Storage - I am going to be looking into what this is and how it works!